# How to handle event bubbling in this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the start, there will be a button on the top and on clicking that button it will make parent div for existing div and all the divs should be draggable inside its parent div.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

function ParentDraggable(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    let startX = e.clientX;
    let startY = e.clientY;

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      setX(x + e.clientX - startX);
      setY(y + e.clientY - startY);
      startX = e.clientX;
      startY = e.clientY;
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Draggable bounds="parent" handle=".handle">
      <div
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          top: y,
          left: x,
          border: "1px solid black",
          width: `${props.w}px`,
          height: `${props.h}px`
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            height: 20,
            backgroundColor: "gray"
          }}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          className="handle"
        >
          Title Bar
        </div>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [parents, setParents] = useState([]);
  const [w, setW] = useState(200);
  const [h, setH] = useState(200);

  const handleAddParent = () => {
    setParents([
      <ParentDraggable w={w} h={h}>
        {parents}
      </ParentDraggable>
    ]);
    setW((prev) => prev + 100);
    setH((prev) => prev + 100);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleAddParent}>AddParent</button>

      <div style={{ height: "98vh" }}>{parents}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When i try to drag any child component its parent div is also getting dragged and I dont that.
Expected - [short video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-iIEKaypmNUQUdlQkOlytWjjFo1GO1K/view)
my code demo - [short video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFbPw30NGyGILOv6N8rjVlCv80PS--tb/view)
check code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-smoke-erw0tt?file=/src/App.js:0-1707)
please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code sandbox seems to be working for me?  i cant reproduce the issue.

Comment: I worked on it and almost working  as expected expectp one thing, innermost div is changing its position when I create new parent div. Ex - create two div, drag inner div to bottom-right and create new parent div, you will notice that innermost div that you had placced in bottom-right of its parent is now at top-left corner of its parent div. I don't want any div to change its position when we create new Parent div.